# Least cost path from single source to single destination without cost distance (calculating accumulative cost)

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, dijkstra

I want to find least cost path from single source to single destination. I am using arcmap and jupyter notebook with arcpy. I have created cost raster. I read a lot but still I do not fully understand the purpose of cost distance tool: why accumulative cost should be calculated? I used Dijsktra algorithm where I directly search for least cost path without calculating accumulative cost first. Will I get not so accurate results if I not apply to my graph something similar like cost distance? This is the dijkstra algoritm (from internet). My question is like why arcmap does not have simplier method for finding least cost path, because now cost distance(or path distance)+cost path should be both runned.

```
import heapq
from sys import stdin, stdout 
 
def dijkstra(adj, source, target):
    INF = ((1<<63) - 1)//2
    pred = { x:x for x in adj }
    dist = { x:INF for x in adj }
    dist[ source ] = 0
    PQ = []
    kk = 0
    heapq.heappush(PQ, [dist[ source ], source])
 
    while(PQ):
        u = heapq.heappop(PQ)  # u is a tuple [u_dist, u_id]
        u_dist = u[0]
        u_id = u[1]
        if u_dist == dist[u_id]:
            for v in adj[u_id]:
               v_id = v[0]
               w_uv = v[1]
               if dist[u_id] +  w_uv < dist[v_id]:
                   dist[v_id] = dist[u_id] + w_uv
                   heapq.heappush(PQ, [dist[v_id], v_id])
                   pred[v_id] = u_id
    st = []            
    if dist[target]==INF:
        print("There is no path between ", source, "and", target)
        return st
    else:
        node = target
        while(True):
            st.append(str(node))
            if(node==pred[node]):
                break
            node = pred[node]
        return st
```

Answer (score 1):

To compute least cost path algorithm **does** calculate accumulative cost => backlink table => path. Yes, no need to memorize cost distance and backlink table when you dealing with single pair:

[image]

However, when you have multiple possible destinations, it's good idea to compute backlink first (saving to raster) and find as many points as you'd like that will reach destination, without re-computing table again and again:

[image]

Yes, you don't need cost distance in this case either. In fact you can specify any raster as cost distance:

[image]

But, this only works for **EACH_CELL** option. When you'd like BEST SINGLE (see below) or EACH_ZONE type of path, it's a huge time saver to have cost distance pre-calculated. You can pick cheapest candidate in no time from it and use backlink table to draw path:

[image]

So, when I compute backlink raster I always specify optional output that is cost distance, because software calculates it anyway. Very little time difference between saving one or two rasters.